# Are there boat tours on Trout River Pond, Gros Morne National Park, Newfoundland?

Tags: canada, tours, newfoundland

The [Western River Brook boat tour page at the Parks Canada website](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/nl/grosmorne/activ/activ2b.aspx) has a photo of a boat tour on Trout River Pond in the south of the park.  [This Gros Morne page makes mention of a Trout River Pond boat tour](http://www.grosmorne.ca/communities.htm).  But on the website of the company supposedly operating it, [Bon Tours](http://www.bontours.ca), I don't find any reference to such a boat tour.

Are there any boat tours on Trout River Pond, Gros Morne National Park, Newfoundland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Ocean Quest](http://www.oceanquestadventures.com/component/content/article/21-tourist/70-gros-morne-national-park) offers one:

> Ocean Quest West is located at Trout River Pond on the south side of Gros Morne National Park, a UNESCO World Heritage Site. Our 2 hour Zodiac and Kayaking adventures bring our guests through 500 million years of history and explores rare and amazing geology such as the Tablelands, a piece of the Earth’s mantle thrust up from the depths of the planet. In addition to the spectacular scenery and geology you will also have the opportunity to view wildlife such as moose, caribou, and black bear and learn about the rich local culture. Our certified and experienced interpretive guides operate 7 days a week from June 10th – September 10th. 9am-5pm Daily. Bilingual guides are available upon request.

Hat tip to http://gowesternnewfoundland.com/activities/trout-river-zodiac-boat-tour/